# gramEvol package Error in 1:possible.choices : argument of length 0

Tags: r, grammar, context-free-grammar, bnf

I am trying to write a grammar but i get  an error

```
Error in 1:possible.choices : argument of length 0
```

here is my grammar

```
library(gramEvol)
rules <- list(
              For = gsrule("for(i in 5:200) {  X[i,] <- <ex>  }"),
              
              ex  = gsrule("<x><op><x>"),
              x   = gsrule("p[i-<i>]","p[i]"),
              i   = gvrule(1:5),
              op  = gsrule("+","-","/","*")
              )
grammar <- CreateGrammar(rules)
gramEvol::GrammarRandomExpression(grammar)
```

the problem is in this line

```
For = gsrule("for(i in 5:200) {  X[i,] <- <ex>  }")
```

without this `<- <ex>` part everything works